# What is the most compact way to represent a database?

Tags: database, representation

I have a database (20 tables, up to a maximum of 17 rows) that I need to represent schematically or graphically on one A4 sheet.

I'm looking for a way to do this, since I only know about ER models and I couldn't manage to squeeze it into a single page.
It could also be a textual representation, as long as it is a standardized way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people call Data Models "ER Diagrams", which is what you appear to be doing; others call ERDs "Data Models".  Don't worry about the common usage terms, we have a lot of non-professionals in the industry these days, who call apples oranges.  Life is much easier when you use the correct labels.

The **Entity Relation Diagram** is a schematic of the Entities and Relations (only), that's why it is called an ER diagram and not a Data Model.  Ten tables will easily fit onto an A4 page.  You will have space to add notes and text.

The **Data Model** is the full schematic of the Entities, Relations and Attributes, with the Primary Key differentiated clearly. Depending on the stage of progress and the audience, or the logical vs physical rendering,  it will additionally show:

- the other Indices (other than the Primary Key)
- DataTypes
- full detail re the Relations
- Associative tables (many-to-many, shown as a Relation at the Logical level; exposed as a table at the Physical level)
- Subtypes/Supertypes fully exposed
- Depending on whether you use the Relational modelling Standard or not, it will show the subtleties and complexities of the data and its Relations.
- Obviously, if you use Standard notation, then you will be understood by more people, and you never have to go back and change it when more people learn the Standard and expect that notation.

Have a look at the Data Model provided in the link below.  The first page is the ERD (28 Entities, while retaining the hierarchy).  The DM is delivered in the subsequent 4 x A4 pages, each containing a logical cluster of tables; and all five pages are linked (make sure you find the notes re links, and click on them).

Even for the DM, I find it is best to present information:

- in manageable or understandable chunks, an A4 page containing a logically related cluster,
- which has to be complete it itself (all the parent tables must be shown), which leads to duplication
- but I never duplicate anything
- therefore I define it once, in its natural cluster, and use a collapsed Entity symbol wherever it is referenced, and link the reference to the full definition.

The other technique that I have found that seriously improves understanding, is to show the objects in their natural hierarchy.  That technique is detailed in the Notation document.

Another option for you, with only ten tables, is to draw the schema at Data Model level, but only show the Primary Keys (exclude non-PK attributes); one small step beyond ERD, and one big step less than full DM.  I do not recommend this, rather, give them the full DM *as well as* the ERD, on however many A4 pages it takes.  People can stop at the first page, or go further if they want.

[**Link to Example ERD & Data Model**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/Order%20DM%20Advanced.pdf)

[**Link to IDEF1X Notation**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Notation.pdf) for those who are unfamiliar with the Relational Modelling Standard.

Comment: Actually, the ER model I've been taught is comprehensive of every attribute for each entity: that's why I couldn't manage to fit it. It looks a lot like the example on page 2 of the first document, only with different graphics. I'll be trying this way, as it seems more compact, and I'll let you know how it works out.

Comment: @Gurzo: I have not heard of an ER **Model**, p2 is a Data Model. The ER **Diagram** is on p1 only. Even the teachers are shocking these days.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: I really have no idea, but a quick Google search brings many results, including https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Er_model . Which is exactly the one I've known, just check the first picture on Wikipedia. Still, I'm going to try your approach.

Comment: @Gurzo. Wiki is a study in mediocrity, the "definitions" entered by amateurs, are forever changing.  If I click on the link, it will contaminate my screen with e-coli.  You're most welcome.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: I too use Wikipedia as a last option, I just linked it since it presented exactly what I've been taught in university about ER models. Thanks again.

Comment: @Gurzo.  (I got e-coli on my screen) Even that one page is inconsistent in itself.  Amateurs.  The heading and start is all about "ER model", but the one horrible model provided is clearly named "ER Diagram".  Next week another amateur will change it.  or add another page, maybe "Data Diagram".

Answer (score 2):

Instead of squeezing all information into a small area, try leaving out the non-essential columns. I don't know what the usage of your representation is, but if it is to be read by humans you should remember that *the denser the information is packed, the more of it will simply be ignored by the human brain* when processing the image.

Less is more, as usual.

Comment: Seems sensible! The only problem is I have to put all the informations on the sheet (it's a definitive document). Would you suggest making a graphic essential and maybe a textual full representation?

Comment: @Gurzo: definitely. Put the comprehensive information in a tabular representation of the columns and their types and constraints. Putting this in an image won't help you. As a side note, even a definitive document might not contain all the information that is available on your application. Some things are only relevant when you actually look at the data or code.